# App for scanning incorrect Code39 barcodes (without start/stop chars)

Tags: iphone, barcode-scanner, zbar-sdk, zbar, code39

I have to read, with an iPhone app, a set of barcodes that have been generated with a Code39 font, but lack the leading/trailing 'asterisk', so that they are considered invalid and simply ignored by any app I've tried (from the App Store).

Apart from the asterisks, the code is well-formatted so I wonder if there is a way to force barcode readers to read that, despite of the missing chars.

I've found sources for Apps (e.g [ZBar](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/)) but they rely on closed libraries...

Any hint?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

code39 requires a start- and a end-symbol, otherwise a scanner doesn't know where the barcodes starts or ends (for example, if you use a barcode within a table). try to mask your string with a star.

```
'*' + ls_yourString + '*'
```

cheers,
http://intermediabay.de/wordpress/

Comment: KKlein, I am using code39 fonts and did the same (adding * before and after string) but I am unable to scan it. I am trying to scan bar code from my Windows phone Lumia 535, using Scanner software. Any idea why it's not recognizing the bar codes?